# Changing file permission in perl

Tags: perl

I am creating a file with below code :

```
open  DINFO, ">>","Mylocation/$NAME/domain_info.txt" or dir $!;
print DINFO "$_[0]:$_[1]:$_[2]\n";
close DINFO;
```

I want "domain_info.txt" file should be created with file permission 644. How can I redirect the permission in code itself. Please help.

Comment: Next time, you should try searching the docs of SO.

Comment: "docs or SO", I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`umask`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/umask.html) from perldoc

> umask
>   Sets the umask for the process to EXPR and returns the previous value. If EXPR is omitted, merely returns the current umask.

```
# newly created files will have 644 permissions
my $old_umask = umask(0777-0644);
# open my $fh, ">>", ..

# set back old umask
umask($old_umask);
```

Comment: Interesting... According to the timestamps, this was posted after the question was closed!

Comment: Note, that assumes the file doesn't already exist, which is rarely the case with `>>`.

Comment: @ikegami `I am creating a file with below code :` <==

Comment: @ikegami There is a 4 hour grace period on the serve side for answering closed questions

Comment: @NathanOliver since when is such policy on closed questions?

Comment: @Сухой27 see this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible

Comment: So you'll apply chmod after every file appending? `:)`

Comment: @Сухой27, The point is (just) `umask` + `open >>` is wrong.

Comment: Of course not, especially when file does not already exist.